# auto animation Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, fade

I have a question, lets say if I have a object and I want it to glow continuously, is this achievable with Jquery? Is there an auto animation function that will loop the fadeIn fadeOut comment? If there is, means I just need two image and toggle fadeIn fadeOut automatically, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/evegih/1/edit)**</kbd>

Let's say you create a `DIV` with background image and inside you put the `IMG` to fade:

```
<div class="fade" style="width:100; height:100; background:url(img1.jpg);">
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
</div>
```

than you can use the `.fadeTo()` callback to loop the fade of your image:

```
var opac=[1, 0.2], c=0;    
(function loop(){
      $('.fade img').fadeTo(400, opac[++c%2], loop);
})();
```

Comment: will try this out! thanks again roXon, you are like my savior totally!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J2KD9/)**</kbd>

You can use `setInterval` function to make loop. One interval must be eqaul the sum of `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` animations. For example:

```
setInterval( function() {
    $( '#comment' ).fadeOut( 800 ).fadeIn( 200 );
}, 1000 );
```